# Jquery Validate Plugin: Highlight/Unhightlight First Error Only

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a form which is laid out inside a table. I am looking for a way to change the background colour of the first table row that contains an error.

Is there a way to target the first error message element when using Hightligh and Unhighlight. The actual DOM part I understand, but I cant seem to find any method of stopping it after the first error

```
  highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
      // Someway of only applying the following style to the first error message
      // ??????????
         $(element).parent("td").parent("tr").css({
             'border':'1px solid #c00',
             'background':'#fff0f0'
             });
        },
 unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
         $(element).parent("td").parent("tr").css({
             'border':'1px solid #ccc',
             'background':'#fff'
             });
```

Comment: Quick question: why would you want to do this? If you have more than one error surely you'd want to show them all otherwise someone would get pretty annoyed at constantly resubmitting the form to only be told about 1 error at a time?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
onfocusin: function (element) {
    // remember the last active field
    this.lastActive = element;
},
highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {  
    // highlight only the last active
    if (this.lastActive && (this.lastActive == element))
        $(element).parent("td").parent("tr").css({
             'border':'1px solid #c00',
             'background':'#fff0f0'
             });   
}
```

Not sure what you mean by first.